# "Context cannot be used while the model is being created" exception with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Why is this happening when we make a call to the AccountApiController.Register() method?

- what is trying to use the context?
- what is trying to create the context?
- how do we avoid this?
- how do we debug this?

> "Message":"An error has occurred.",
>
> "ExceptionMessage":"The context cannot be used while the model is
>   being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used
>   inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members
>   of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.",
>
> "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
>
> "StackTrace":"
>
> at System.Web.Http.ApiController.d__1.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter
>   .HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task > task)
>
> at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__0.MoveNext()"

Comment: Make sure that you don't use the same context object for different requests and make sure that you send request after OnModelCreating. you can add there breakpoint in end of method.

Comment: How do we make sure that we don't use the same context object for different requests? Also, I am not sure what you mean by adding a breakpoint because we don't have an OnModelCreating method.

Comment: I've learned that the ASP.NET Identity uses the Factory Pattern in order to get one instance of UserManager per request; this might be a problem, because our UserManager stores data in our DbContext. Hmm.

Comment: try to make your methods Async, this might solve the problem

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem was that we were NOT using the factory pattern that [MS recommends](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx?PageIndex=2).

> You can use Factory implementation to get an instance of UserManager
>   from the OWIN context. ... This is a recommended way of getting an instance of
>   UserManager per request for the application.

As a result, "the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently," because several requests and thus threads shared a DbContext.

**This following is correct.** It creates a new instance of MyDbContext for each call to the UserManagerFactory function.

```
UserManagerFactory 
= () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new MyDbContext()));
```

**The following is incorrect.** It look similar but does not create a new instance for each call to UserManagerFactory. It is what we were using, ergo our site broke.

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new MyDbContext());                    
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
UserManagerFactory = () => userManager;
```

Comment: Where should I put this on my project? I use Unity.Mvc as a dependency resolver. Also, I work with my own UnityOfWork which I inject a DbContext that is shared to all my repositories.

Comment: I had the same error message, this fixed my problem as well. @ShaunLuttin

Comment: Same problem here and fixed by adding factory pattern. Thanks @ShaunLuttin

Answer (score 25):

This error can also occur in case of incorrect `connectionString`. Check if `connectionString` is valid (no typo etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Do you override the OnModelCreating method? If so, can you share it or the whole context class?

If not, you should pay attention to the following in the error message

> or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

If that doesn't help, do you use an unchanged Web API project which is created by Visual Studio?

Comment: We do not override the OnModelCreating method.Also, we do not use an unchanged Web API project... rather, we have modified the DbContext which stores both ASP.NET Identity data and other website data.

Comment: We aren't sure how to determine whether the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

**TL&DR**:  If the goal is model seeding, and you are using the entity framework, i strongly suggest you take a look at the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

This link details how to directly SEED your data, during the migration itself. This is typically useful when you want to seed your data during the creation of the DATABASE instead of the start of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting records from Table/View make sure you have sufficient access on the DB objects.

I had the same problem and i resolved it by executing

```
sp_change_users_login [ @Action = ] 'action' [ , [ @UserNamePattern = ] 'user' ] [ , [ @LoginName = ] 'login' ] [ , [ @Password = ] 'password' ] [;]


sp_change_users_login 'update_one' 'dbuser' 'dblogin'
```

[Find more snippet and details](http://www.asptricks.net/2017/05/dbcontext-and-related-classes-are-not.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using EF Code First in a multi-layered architecture with MySQL and had the same exception and using the following line inside the DBContext Class constructure works:

```
Database.SetInitializer<EntitiesName>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the main Answer by **Shaun Luttin** but also,

In my case: after the deployment i take this error and i found the reason is using the Hsts Preload after inserting SSL certificate. Uncommenting this lines solved the redirection, and it solved this error completely

```
 //app.UseHsts(options => options.MaxAge(days: 18 * 7).IncludeSubdomains().Preload());
```