# What am i doing wrong? : Context Cannot be used while the model is being Created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm stucked with this problem and i've spent more than 3 hours scouring the web and SO for a solution to no avail. My Code keeps throwing this error

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This is my Context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ApprovalStatus> ApprovalStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Documents> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EducationLevel> EducationLevel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmploymentDetail> EmploymentDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmploymentStatus> EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GuestPersonalDetail> GuestPersonalDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LGA> LocalGovts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LoanDetail> LoanDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MaritalStatus> MaritalStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NameTitle> NameTitles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NextOfKin> NextOfKins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RejectionReasons> RejectionReasons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RepaymentMode> RepaymentModes { get; set; }
}
```

in my controller i have this where i try to populate a dropdownlist in my view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Apply()
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    ApplicationVM model = new ApplicationVM();
        model.BankList = new SelectList(db.Banks, "Bankid", "BankName");
        model.EducationLevellist = new SelectList(db.EducationLevel, "EducationLevelid", "Level");
        model.EmploymentStatuslist = new SelectList(db.EmploymentStatus, "EmploymentStatusid", "EmpStatus");
        model.GenderList = new SelectList(db.Genders, "Genderid", "GenderVal");
        model.LGAlist = new SelectList(db.LocalGovts, "LGAid", "LgName");
        model.MaritalStatusList = new SelectList(db.MaritalStatuses, "MaritalStatusid", "Status");
        model.NameTitleList = new SelectList(db.NameTitles, "NameTitleid", "Title");
        model.RepaymentModeList = new SelectList(db.RepaymentModes, "RepaymentModeid", "ModeOfRepayment");
        return View(model);           
}
```

i used this in view like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicantTitleid, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ApplicantTitleid, Model.NameTitleList, null, String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicantTitleid)
    </div>
</div>
```

The error is being thrown at the Dropdownlistfor point. This is the stack trace

```
[InvalidOperationException: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +115
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +138
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +38
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +108
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +157
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +133
   System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField() +461
   System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList.GetListItems() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList.GetEnumerator() +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.GetSelectListWithDefaultValue(IEnumerable`1 selectList, Object defaultValue, Boolean allowMultiple) +557
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, String optionLabel, String name, IEnumerable`1 selectList, Boolean allowMultiple, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +574
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, String expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IEnumerable`1 selectList, String optionLabel, Object htmlAttributes) +142
   ASP._Page_Views_Loan_Apply_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\RIDWAN\Documents\visual studio 2013\projects\ApplicationPortal\ApplicationPortal\Views\Loan\Apply.cshtml:37
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +120
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +63
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +100
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +131
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +932
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +188
```

What am i doing wrong exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Context cannot be used while the model is being created" exception with ASP.NET Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344232/context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-created-exception-with-asp-net)

Comment: @MethodMan i've spent more than 3 hours scouring the web and SO for a solution to no avail. I believe that's what I said. Trust me I wouldn't have spent 3 hours on SO, u want to see my search results or what.

Comment: Have you tried pulling the object lists into their own vars before creating a selectlist from them? I'd also recommend moving the call to the database into its own dboperations style class.  But something like `var bankList = db.Banks.ToList();  var BankSelectList = new SelectList(bankList, "Bankid", "BankName");`