# The context cannot be used while the model is being created . two context file how can i manage

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

The old programmer make connection using `.edmx` file and now I use the make connection using **EFPowerTools** so how can I manage the code..

Comment: Can you paste your code here, the code that throws the exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Context cannot be used while the model is being created" exception with ASP.NET Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344232/context-cannot-be-used-while-the-model-is-being-created-exception-with-asp-net)